# WildFly 8.2 unable to configure for external property file

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8

I am using the wildly 8.2 final , facing the configuration with external property file. My requirement is like this i am using jboss 5 earlier for locally . we were placed property file in this location `jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\conf` and using in application ear (spring property file configuration), but  in wild fly we are unable to configuring i tried modules also, i.e we used the property file with out package

Answer (score 0):

Specify location in `standalone.bat` file inside bin folder as shown below

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% - DpropertyName.config.dir=Path_to_config
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a module and putting your property files inside the module is the way to go.

Ensure the following:

1. That your module directory is created correctly, such as `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/company/package/main`.
2. That you have a valid module.xml file in the directory. It should look like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.company.package">
       <resources>
           <resource-root path="."/>
       </resources>
   </module>
   ```
3. Your property file(s) is in the directory.